# Whats wrong with simple html NSString?

Tags: html, iphone, ios, uiwebview

Hey guys I have a simple html `NSString`, it works fine on the browser but does not load on the iPhone. I am using a simple:  `[self.w loadHTMLString:errorString baseURL:nil]`. What am I missing?

```
NSString* errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"<html><body> <iframe src=\"http://64.183.101.142:81/pda.htm\"width=\"500\" height=\"500\"></iframe></body></html>"];
```

Comment: The HTML doesn't look complete...

Comment: @futureelite7 Whats missing? the html works fine in a browser so I assume the necessary parts were there.

Comment: I think the url link that u r trying to opne ie "http://64.183.101.142:81/pda.htm" needs some authentication.

Comment: @SatishAzad Ya, theres a username, but no password. How can I modify it to make it work? Please help me Im running out of time.

Comment: see my answer in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to first load your request or HTML on webview and Capture this request using a UIWebViewDelegate method with following protocol

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {

      //capture request =>  request
       //From here you have the NSURLRequest object
  //You can extract the headers of the request to NSDictionary which will contain   //the         
//authentication cookie details, token, etc. using the following method of NSURLRequest
        //- (NSDictionary *)allHTTPHeaderFields

    }
```

Source [Source link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632185/how-to-authenticate-ios-iphone-users-with-remote-web-application-and-re-use-auth)

Answer (score 0):

If it requires authentication you will need to modify your string depending on the type of request.

if it's a get it will have a "?" at the and the parameters something like this:
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:81/pda.htm?user="userX"&passwd="something"  if it's a post method you will pass your data within the body of your request. [NSURLRequest setHTTPBody:];

I hope this helps.